# Desktop programming tool similar to App Inventor for Android

Tags: android, app-inventor

Is there a desktop based programming tool similar to [App Inventor for Android](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/)(`this is web-based`) for end users who do not know any programming language?

Comment: Also asked at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4032/desktop-programming-tool-similar-to-app-inventor-for-android

Answer (score 1):

HyperNext Android Creator is a desktop based programming tool aimed at beginner Android  programmers. Currently it only runs on Windows platform but OS X version is in development. Users do not have to know Java or understand the Android SDK as it uses an English-like scripting language and its IDE has a built in screen designer.

There is an Hello World tutorial here:-

http://www.hypernextandroid.com/hnfiles/progfirst.html

A free trial version that builds apps/games for both Android devices and Emulator can be found here:-

http://www.hypernextandroid.com/index.html

There is also a projects page and some .apk demo files for downlaoding straight onto Android device.

Comment: thanks..inspired by Apple's HyperCard in early 90s by any chance ? also, I could not find any page for looking at example code without downloading.

Comment: Yes somewhere they say inspired from Hypercard. I guess not many people have heard of HyperCard these days. They now have some sample scripts up.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that comes remotely close to that would be [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) and then using an  [Exe Creator](http://scratch.mit.edu/forums/viewtopic.php?id=46159)

Comment: app inventor is from the MIT developers who developed Scratch, however the tools are for different domains..App Inventor has more domain specific features which end users can readily use for mobile phone oriented apps with touchscreen.

Answer (score 0):

For making apps with app inventor you need not need any programming experience at all. The code is framed itself, you just have to put in your imagination into logic (in blocks editor)

Comment: thanks for the info...please read the question more clearly for the exact requirements